# Performing transformation for multiple columns in one go in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with multiple columns for word form tags, as in this mock example:

```
df <- data.frame(
   w1 = c("NN1", "NN0", "ADJ", "ADC", "NP0", "VVZ"),
   w2 = c("NN0", "NN2", "ADC", "NN0", "VBN", "NN1"),
   w3 = c("ADJ", "NN2", "NP0", "VVG", "ADS", "NN1"),
   w4 = c("NN2", "NN2", "ADJ", "ADJ", "ADS", "VVD")
 )
df
```

Now I want to re-classify the tags using broader descriptions, such as "noun" for singular nouns (tagged "NN1"), plural nouns ("NN2"), proper nouns ("NP0") etc. I can do this transformation column by column, like this:

```
df$w1_class <- ifelse(grepl("^N", df$w1), "noun", 
                      ifelse(grepl("^V", df$w1), "verb", "adjective"))
df$w2_class <- ifelse(grepl("^N", df$w2), "noun", 
                      ifelse(grepl("^V", df$w2), "verb", "adjective"))
df$w3_class <- ifelse(grepl("^N", df$w3), "noun", 
                      ifelse(grepl("^V", df$w3), "verb", "adjective"))
df$w4_class <- ifelse(grepl("^N", df$w4), "noun", 
                      ifelse(grepl("^V", df$w4), "verb", "adjective"))
```

If one has many more such columns and many more tag types, as I do in my real dataframe, then this is a tedious exercise given the highly repetitive code. Can the transformations be done in one go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution using `dplyr::mutate_all` and `dplyr::case_when` can be as:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate_all(funs(case_when(
  grepl("^N", .) ~ "noun",
  grepl("^V", .) ~ "verb",
  grepl("^A", .) ~ "adjective",
  TRUE           ~ "Other"
                 )))

#          w1        w2        w3        w4
# 1      noun      noun adjective      noun
# 2      noun      noun      noun      noun
# 3 adjective adjective      noun adjective
# 4 adjective      noun      verb adjective
# 5      noun      verb adjective adjective
# 6      verb      noun      noun      verb
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(
  w1 = c("NN1", "NN0", "ADJ", "ADC", "NP0", "VVZ"),
  w2 = c("NN0", "NN2", "ADC", "NN0", "VBN", "NN1"),
  w3 = c("ADJ", "NN2", "NP0", "VVG", "ADS", "NN1"),
  w4 = c("NN2", "NN2", "ADJ", "ADJ", "ADS", "VVD")
)
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem (probably my fault): when I run the above code what I get is this: 

`df[1:10,]
   slots rows
1      1    1
2      2    2
3      3    3
4      4    4
5      5    5
6      6    6
7      7    7
8      8    8
9      9    9
10    10   10`

Comment: Did you the above code on same data frame? If not please run with data.frame in sample in question once. Just to get confidence on working answer. If it still spent work on real data frame then share 10 rows from it as part of question.

Comment: My sincere apologies, I inadvertently DID run the code on an entirely different dataframe. Your code works *perfectly well* on the one used in the question and your answer! Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You can put your mapping logic in a function and then use `dplyr::mutate_all`:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
    w1 = c("NN1", "NN0", "ADJ", "ADC", "NP0", "VVZ"),
    w2 = c("NN0", "NN2", "ADC", "NN0", "VBN", "NN1"),
    w3 = c("ADJ", "NN2", "NP0", "VVG", "ADS", "NN1"),
    w4 = c("NN2", "NN2", "ADJ", "ADJ", "ADS", "VVD"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

foo <- function(tags) {
    tags <- sub("^N.*", "noun", tags)
    tags <- sub("^V.*", "verb", tags)
    tags <- sub("^A.*", "adjective", tags)
    tags
}

out <- df %>%
  mutate_all(foo) %>%
  rename_all(~paste0(., "_class"))
```

Comment: when running the code now I get this error: `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: `as_dictionary()` is defunct as of rlang 0.3.0.
Please use `as_data_pronoun()` instead.` How should the code be changed?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann are you sure you have the newest `dplyr`? I don't get an error, though I did get a deprecation warning, so I adjusted the code.

Comment: Yes, I've updated dplyr twice today, even shut down RStudio but still get the same error even with your new code