# Mutating data in multiple columns using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

This is an updated question to an earlier question ([Performing transformation for multiple columns in one go in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50887194/performing-transformation-for-multiple-columns-in-one-go-in-r)); the solutions suggested then now throw an error (see below).

I have a dataframe with multiple columns for word form tags, as in this mock example:

```
df <- data.frame(
    w1 = c("NN1", "NN0", "AJ0", "AJC", "NP0", "VVZ"),
    w2 = c("NN0", "NN2", "AJC", "NN0", "VBN", "NN1"),
    w3 = c("AJ0", "NN2", "NP0", "VVG", "AJS", "NN1"),
    w4 = c("NN2", "NN2", "AJ0", "AJ0", "AJS", "VVD")
  )
```

I need to re-classify the tags using broader descriptions, such as "noun" for singular nouns (tagged "NN1"), plural nouns ("NN2"), proper nouns ("NP0") etc.
One solution suggested earlier was this, based on `dplyr`:

```
 df %>% mutate_all(funs(case_when(
  grepl("^N", .) ~ "noun",
  grepl("^V", .) ~ "verb",
  grepl("^A", .) ~ "adjective",
  TRUE           ~ "Other"
)))
```

It worked well back then but now no longer does; it throws this error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: `as_dictionary()` is defunct as of rlang 0.3.0.
Please use `as_data_pronoun()` instead.
```

Can anybody help: what needs to be done to get the code working again?

Comment: Try `df %>% 
 mutate_all(list(~ case_when(
 grepl("^N", .) ~ "noun",
 grepl("^V", .) ~ "verb",
 grepl("^A", .) ~ "adjective",
 TRUE           ~ "Other")))`.

Comment: @tmfmnk No, this gets the same error

Comment: Try to update to the latest `dplyr` version. It's working fine on my computer.

Comment: doesn't work either

Comment: Please add your `sessionInfo()` to the question.

Comment: What other packages are you loading? you could try adding `dplyr::` before each of the dplyr functions in case something is pointing to the wrong package.

Comment: sessionInfo() 1/2
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.14.1 Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

Comment: sessionInfo() 2/2 locale:
[1] C
attached base packages:
[1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets  methods base     
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1 rstudioapi_0.7 magrittr_1.5 R6_2.2.2 rlang_0.3.1      tools_3.4.0     
 [7] assertthat_0.2.0 crayon_1.3.4 glue_1.3.1 compiler_3.4.0 pillar_1.4.1 pkgconfig_2.0.1